# Will ISS grow further

Tags: iss, space-station

Are there plans to keep building the ISS? In particular adding more modules and generally expanding it.
If not, are there some fundamental limitations on its expansion? Like power, cooling, or something else.

Answer (score 5):

The USOS (US Operating Segment) is basically complete with some minor exceptions.

SpaceX CRS-8 mission (Due Feb 2016) is scheduled to bring a BEAM (Bigelow Expandable Module) to the station for a test of inflatables at the station.

SpaceX CRS-7 was carrying the IDA-1 (International Docking Adapter) and was lost.  CRS-9 will carry IDA-2. They will build IDA-3 out of spare for launch on CRS-14 I think.  These are minor plugins for the PMA (Pressurized Mating Adapters) so that the commercial crew vehicles can dock using the NDS/LIDS docking systems.

The ROS (Russian Operating Segment) is still waiting to replace the Pirs docking module with a new module known as Nauka, that will be earth facing. This module will then have a docking port at the bottom and a new airlock. The OM module (stands for something in Russian I cannot type) that will be a ball module with 6 docking ports.  Then at least two more modules.  Good examples and images in this answer.

[Will the ISS need more docking ports?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/will-the-iss-need-more-docking-ports)

Comment: MLM is...problematic.  From Wikipedia "The launch of Nauka, initially planned for 2007, has been repeatedly delayed. During 2013, the launch was re-scheduled to April 2014 and then to June 2014; NASA documents at that time indicated that the module would not fly before November 2015. In April 2014 it emerged that the target date for launch was postponed to February 2017, as it became necessary to manufacture a new propulsion system for the module." A 10 year delay (and counting).

Comment: @OrganicMarble So you are saying it is still more on schedule than SLS?  :)

Comment: Lol, have an upvote!